# Boolean that checks if a button is clicked does not work for some reason

Tags: java, android-studio

I have been searching in this forum about how to make a boolean that switches to true when it is clicked. In my program I have two buttons: Yes and no. When I click them, in the `onClick` method, the boolean switches to true, but in the rest of the code it stays false.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 


    static boolean yesisclicked=false; 
    static boolean noisclicked=false; 




    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


        final Button comment; 

        final Button yes; 
        final Button no; 

comment =findViewById(R.id.comment); 



yes= findViewById(R.id.yes); 
no = findViewById(R.id.no); 



yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
yesisclicked=true; 
                noisclicked=false; 


            } 
        }); 
        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                noisclicked=true; 
yesisclicked=false; 


            } 
        }); 
comment.setText(""+noisclicked);
```

Why does that happen and how do I solve that?

Comment: Hello, it seems that you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because your code snippet is missing important details about how you have defined your boolean variables `yesisclicked` and `noisclicked` and how you refer to them in the rest of your code.

Comment: Ok, just added some relevant code

Comment: Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing buttons and static booleans with the same name and in your onclick handlers you seem to be using some variables with local scope.

I guess this should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static boolean yesClicked = false;
    static boolean noClicked  = false;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button comment = findViewById(R.id.comment);
        final Button yes = findViewById(R.id.yes);
        final Button no  = findViewById(R.id.no);

        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yesClicked = true;
                noClicked  = false;
                // comment.setText("Yes clicked!" + yesClicked);
            }
        });

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                yesClicked = false;
                noClicked  = true;
                // comment.setText("No clicked! " + noClicked);
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made a mistake while writing it into stack overflow. Of course the booleans should be named differently. I have just corrected it. Thanks a lot for telling me the mistake. Now the code is written, as he is supposed to be and the problem persists... I am very sorry for my mistake. The button does not change...

Comment: You mean you have corrected the code and the problem still persists that is the booleans `yesClicked` and `noClicked` still do not change their values?

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that a new anonymous class is generated in  onClick and the code does not have an influence to the outside?

Comment: No, inner classes have access to the static fields of the enclosing class.  Add debug messages to the click handlers and you should see their values change.

Comment: "D/MainActivity: nohasbeenpressedinside ", here, when I press no, only the inside press is loged. Is that what you mean I should do?

Comment: What is _inside press_??  Please provide relevant code including log messages inside click handlers and how you detect that the corresponding static boolean has not changed outside the handler.

Comment: There is line `comment.setText(""+noisclicked);` in your code.  Where do you call it? If you call it from `onCreate` method after creating the click handlers, it will not print updated value to the `comment`.

Comment: Yes it is after the click handlers. And with "inside" I mean in the click handlers

Comment: It outputs false

Comment: Look, do you really expect your code to output `true` for the boolean values from `onCreate` method?  Hint: `onCreate` method completes _before_ you press any button, yes or no.

Comment: Should I make another method then? How do I do it, without that the same happens as in onCreate?

Comment: It is enough for you to print debug message for the changed booleans inside the click handlers.  You may add set the text of comment _inside_click_handlers_ too: `comment.setText("Yes: " + yesClicked + "; No: " + noClicked);`  If you _really_ need to track those changes outside independently on the click event, you may setup some timer and log the status of the booleans each 5 or 10 sec.

Comment: Yes I actually need it for a quiz in which the program guesses the planet a person is thinking about.

Comment: So it has to continue independently